# How to install compiler and binutils on FreeNAS?

Tags: freebsd, freenas

I'd like to run a backup tool, [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/), that apparently requires a `cc` compiler and `binutils`.  I'm able to locate and install the required BSD packages for python, gcc, and dependencies from [ftp2.freebsd.org](ftp://ftp2.freebsd.org/).  However, I can't find `binutils`.

How are `binutils` installed on a system like FreeNAS?  I'm working with FreeNAS 0.70 (based on FreeBSD 7.2).  I see several packages with `binutils` in the name, but it's not clear any of them are for my i386 platform.

e.g. I see `i386-rtems-binutils-2.19.1`, but I can't find any info that suggests this is correct for my platform.  Google results mention it's for realtime systems.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes simpler is better.  With BSD you can say something like this:

```
# pkg_add -r binutils
```

and it will fetch the latest version from a repository and install.

One advantage of the -r (remote fetch) is that it fetches a "meta" package, and doesn't need the exact version number etc.

Comment: One up: How can this package be downloaded if the machine doesn't have a direct internet connection?  That's why I was browsing the FTP site for package files.  I didn't see a binutils.tbz file.

Comment: I didn't realize you were doing the FTP from a different machine.