# How to install GCC or a compiler on FreeNAS 7.2

Tags: unix, nas, bsd, freenas

I have a NAS, running FreeNAS 0.7.2 (FreeBSD 7.3).

I have tried to install Flexget, but it requires some pysqlite dependency. I have python 2.6 and python-setuptools.

`Running pysqlite-2.6.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-rlGbDw/pysqlite-2.6.0/egg-dist-tmp-19vzBL 

unable to execute cc: No such file or directory 

error: Setup script exited with error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`

From my knowledge, this means it doesnt have a cc compiler available to it?
How do I go about installing GCC on FreeNAS, as it doesnt come with any build tools (GCC, make etc).

I've read another question on here about it  [How to install compiler and binutils on FreeNAS?](https://superuser.com/questions/196170/how-to-install-compiler-and-binutils-on-freenas)

However that user only explained they visited ftp2.freebsd.org - which I've done for the past 15 mins (searching around in it).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the following:

- If possible, upgrade your box to FreeNAS 9.1.1 (0.7.2 is considered paleolithic at this point),
- Create a jail,
- Login to the jail and install FlexGet.  You might be able to get away with the command `pkg-add -r py-flexget` (Check that the [available packaged version](http://www.freshports.org/www/py-flexget) is suitable for your purposes.)

In general, custom services should be added within jails.  Modifying the core FreeNAS rootfs is frowned upon, as it complicates system upgrades.